# necesito calcular el mayor, el menor, el promedio, el valor de venta y el valor de venta mayor a 100000 pero no me funciona

Tags: java

```
package quiz;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ferreteria {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Ferreteria objFerreteria=new Ferreteria();
        objFerreteria.contadorVentas();
}
int clientes;
double valorProducto;
int UnidadesPorCliente;
double valorVenta;
double valorMayor;
double valorMenor;
double promedioVentas;
double mayor100000;


public void contadorVentas() {
int valor;

Scanner teclado=new Scanner(System.in);

for(int contador=0;contador<100000;contador++) {

    System.out.println("ingrese numero");
    valor=teclado.nextInt();

valorProducto=teclado.nextInt();
System.out.println("el valor del producto es "+valorProducto);
valorMayor=teclado.nextInt();
System.out.println("el numero mayor es "+ valorMayor);
valorMenor=teclado.nextInt();
System.out.println("el numero menor es "+ valorMenor);
mayor100000=teclado.nextInt();
System.out.println("el numero menor es "+ mayor100000);
UnidadesPorCliente=teclado.nextInt();
System.out.println("las unidades por cliente fueron="+UnidadesPorCliente);
promedioDeVentas();

}

}
private void mayorA100000(int valor) {
if(valor>100000) {
    mayor100000++;
}
}
private void promedioDeVentas() {
    promedioVentas=UnidadesPorCliente/valorProducto;
}
private void mayoriaDeValor() {
    valorMayor=valorVenta+valorMayor;
}
private void valorTotalVenta() {
    valorVenta=valorProducto+valorVenta;
}
}
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el propósito de tener un for con 100000 iteraciones? ¿Qué desea lograr? ¿Qué funciona en su código o qué no funciona ? ¿Muestra algún error?  tal y como está no está muy claro , al menos para mi. :)

Answer (score 2):

Tienes unos cuantos errores aquí y allá y cosas que están de más.

**Primero:**
No haces uso de las siguientes librerías, puedes eliminarlas:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
```

**Segundo:** En el `main`, por qué haces un objeto de la clase para llamar al método `contadorVentas()`?. Con el uso de `static` puedes solucionar este problema. Haces que el método sea `static`, ejemplo `public static void contadorVentas()` y puedes llamar al método directamente sin necesidad de una instancia de tu propia clase. Recuerda que una clase, método o campo declarado como `static` puede ser accedido o invocado sin la necesidad de tener que instanciar un objeto de la clase.

**Tercero:** Por qué tu `main` está vacío y toda tu lógica está dentro del método `contadorVentas()`?. Los métodos, funciones o procedimientos deben de ser usados para resolver cosas fácil y rápidamente. Te aconsejo que traslades tu lógica al `main` y utilices los demás métodos que tienes debajo.

**Cuarto:** Por qué las declaraciones de tus variables las tienes debajo de `main`?. Si no es necesario que sean globales, entonces debes declararlas dentro del `main`.

**Quinto:** Nunca cierras el Scanner. Al finalizar con él, debes cerrarlo de la siguiente manera: `teclado.close();`

**Sexto:** Tienes métodos tipo `void` y no retornas nada.

**Séptimo:** Por qué tienes el `for` hasta 100000? o.o Creo que entre 5-10 es suficiente.

**Octavo:** Por qué muestras los mayores, menores, etc.. dentro del mismo `for`?. Lo correcto sería pedir primero los números y al salir del `for` entonces mostrar los resultados.

**Noveno:** Tienes `valorProducto` declarado como tipo `Double`, entonces para capturar un `Double` con el `Scanner` necesitas `.nextDouble();`

Entre muchos otros errores.... Tu programa se puede simplificar mucho. Lo he hecho por ti y lo he comentado para que puedas entenderlo. No logré entender a qué te refieres con "valor de venta" y con "valor mayor a 100,000" pero, he hecho lo que he creído. Puedes editarlo a tu gusto.

**Tu programa arreglado, corregido y haciendo lo que necesitas:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Ferreteria {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Creamos un ArrayList de tipo Double
        ArrayList<Double> valores = new ArrayList<Double>();

        // Lógica
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Pediremos 3 valores
        for (int contador = 0; contador < 3; contador++) {

            System.out.println("Valor del producto #" + contador + ": ");
            // Agregamos el valor capturado al ArrayList
            valores.add(teclado.nextDouble());

        }

        // Cerrar Scanner
        teclado.close();

        // Calcular el mayor
        double valorMayor = 0;
        for (int contador = 0; contador < valores.size(); contador++) {

            // Si el valor en la posición "contador" es mayor a "valorMayor"
            if (valores.get(contador) > valorMayor) {
                valorMayor = valores.get(contador);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("El valor mayor es: " + valorMayor);

        // Calcular el menor
        double valorMenor = valorMayor;
        for (int contador = 0; contador < valores.size(); contador++) {

            // Si el valor en la posición "contador" es menor a "valorMenor"
            if (valores.get(contador) < valorMenor) {
                valorMenor = valores.get(contador);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("El valor menor es: " + valorMenor);

        // Calcular el promedio
        double valorPromedio = 0;
        for (int contador = 0; contador < valores.size(); contador++) {

            // Sumamos todos los valores
            valorPromedio += valores.get(contador);
        }
        // Dividimos entre el número de valores que tenga el ArrayList
        System.out.println("El valor promedio es: " + valorPromedio / valores.size());

        // Valor de venta
        double valorVentaTotal = 0;
        for (int contador = 0; contador < valores.size(); contador++) {

            // Sumamos todos los valores
            valorVentaTotal += valores.get(contador);
        }
        System.out.println("El valor de venta total es: " + valorVentaTotal);

        // Cantidad de ventas mayores a 100,000
        int cantidadVentasMayores = 0;
        for (int contador = 0; contador < valores.size(); contador++) {

            // Si el valor en la posición "contador" es mayor a 100,000
            if (valores.get(contador) > 100000) {
                cantidadVentasMayores++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Productos que exceden los 100,000: " + cantidadVentasMayores);
    }

}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero haberte ayudado!.